# How to add Autodesk Forge Viewer Extensions to React?

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

I want to add my Autodesk forge viewer extensions to React. Is it possible and how can i do this?
Now i have a viewer which work in React, but extensions still working with pure js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/ is built using react, it has many forge viewer extensions.

Github Repo: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs

Here's an example of loading forge viewer extension in react project:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/89e2e0af1d87e3b948cb66bc88f54140c6e8a0e8/src/client/components/Viewer/Viewer.Configurator/Viewer.Configurator.js#L871

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i use it?

Comment: what is it? is it like library?

Comment: It's react component. it depends on your extension, if the extension has UI elements, you can use react components. Alternately you can just load the extension in vanilla js like `viewer.loadExtension(element.name);`

Comment: If you have anymore doubt, please ask. if the information provided was useful, please accept the answer.